# How to sign a simple transfer TX with digitalbitbox python api

Tags: python, pyethereum, rlp

I'm trying to sign a simple transfer transaction using digitalbitbox's python api ([see here](https://github.com/digitalbitbox/mcu/tree/master/py) and code snippet below).

I send the following json to the HW wallet api:

*Sending: {"sign":{"data":[{"keypath":"m/1/1/1/0", "hash":"f2243e10c5c4f4ca1ba2f4cac89e5996ede01c101c8f510440a027b5faaf96a7"}]}}*

The signed TX hash returned by the HW wallet is:

*0653b763d72e0dc39624310f88b1bda611e94611c5f79ad75132d4305f25dc2c3aac17c3c94a519fbc7da3b9c898a7fae26c68d49d13b604ea8a7ceaad0f1da9*

However, when pasting this into etherscan I receive the following error:

*Error! Unable to broadcast Tx : {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"rlp: expected input list for types.txdata"}}*

I was expecting too see some error message like insufficient funds, but it seems like my encoding is wrong.

Does anybody know why this isn't working?

```
import sys
from dbb_utils import *
import time
import rlp

try:
    password = 'password'
    openHid()

    # Start up options - factory reset; initial password setting
    if 0:
        hid_send_encrypt('{"reset":"__ERASE__"}', password)
        hid_send_plain('{"password":"' + password + '"}')
        sys.exit()

    import ethereum
    from ethereum.transactions import Transaction
    import hashlib

    # Create test TX
    testTx = Transaction(nonce=5, gasprice=24000000000, startgas=21000, to=int("0xfc5d975c3738b1eed1f072d72912bea31f9d1eb1", 16), value=1, data="")
    rawTx = ethereum.utils.encode_hex(ethereum.utils.sha3(rlp.encode(testTx))) #hashlib.sha256(rlp.encode(testTx)).hexdigest()
    message = '{"sign":{"data":[{"keypath":"m/1/1/1/0", "hash": "' + rawTx + '"}]}}'

    # Send a JSON command
    response = hid_send_encrypt(message, password)
    print(response)
    print("*"*40)
    cmd = '{"sign":""}'
    response = hid_send_encrypt(message, password)
    print(response)

except IOError as ex:
    print(ex)
except(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print("Exiting code")

dbb_hid.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I forgot to add the signature into the transaction object. After adding the associated v, r and s parameters to the raw TX and computing the corresponding hex of the rlp encoded TX it now seems to work!